# Tricky div stacking

Tags: html, css

I have three `<div>s`, A, B, and C. They are all lines of text. The basic layout is:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa     ccccccccccccccccccccccccc
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

When the window is opened fully, the cccccccccccc can be kerned (i.e can fit) above the bbbbbbbbb and therefore I want it to do so, as illustrated above.

However, when the window is reduced in size such that either A and C can't fit on the same line, I want ccccccccccc to move below bbbbbbbbb, like this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

Therefore, I somehow need to make the default position of C to the right of A, but to make C move below B when there isn't enough space to accommodate C in its full length (and I **don't** want any line-wrapping).

Placing A and B together in a containing `<div>` and having C follow that `<div>` simply doesn't work, as I want C to be next to A, on the same line, in its default positioning; if I wrapped A and B into a dedicated `<div>` container, I'd end up with:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb   ccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

...and that's not what I want. (I'd also likely end up with text-line wrapping of B and C, and I'm trying to avoid that.)

How can this be most efficiently accomplished?

Comment: You should look into Bootstrap's grid system. This allows you to specify what layout you'd like for each screen size.

Comment: @Tom do a, b and c have a fixed width?

Answer (score 2):

**I've Solved it...no JQuery required, just judicious styling:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div style="float:left">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
<div style="float:left; width:100%">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:top">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
```

**See it in action here:** https://jsfiddle.net/TomJS/wj44qqe4/